# Shade Smooth looks weird

Tags: rendering, objects

I created a dice, the last step should be "Shade Smooth". After that, the surface looks weird. The problem is after render the same. Does anybody how to solve it?
Left one is before Shade Smooth, right one after it.
[image]

Comment: you must have bad topology here, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

this is the standard way to create a hole inside a plane (you can do it manually or with few clicks with loopToops addon): as you can see, there are only quads and this will allow you to add subdivision modifier or shade smooth with not strange artifacts

[image]